# Firefox stopped working with our app after 36.0.1

Tags: web-application, certificate, browser, firefox

We have a web application that works on all browsers and firefox before 36.0.1

Have done all the typical things, clearing cache, reinstalling ff, etc. Multiple different machine from different locations have been tested as well.

Our certs are up to date but this site currently is tls version 1.0 only, it's a legacy data center most folks are on a new platform and it works there... it has tls 1.1 n 1.2 but still seems like it should be working? It allows a secure connection to the first page and then when you execute the app from there is comes back with "secure connection reset". I can see the rst pkt coming from our systems as well but nothing else telling. As before, it works w/ all other browsers and firefox before the most recent version.

Report from SSLLabs:

```
Prefix handling            Both (with and without WWW) 
Valid from                 Mon Jun 04 17:00:00 PDT 2012 
Valid until                Wed Aug 05 05:00:00 PDT 2015 (expires in 4 months and 16 days) 
Key                        RSA 2048 bits (e 65537) 
Weak key (Debian)          No 
Issuer                     DigiCert High Assurance CA-3 
Signature algorithm        SHA1withRSA WEAK
Extended Validation        No 
Revocation information     CRL, OCSP 
Revocation status          Good (not revoked) 
Trusted                    Yes

Additional Certificates (if supplied) 
Certificates provided      3 (4322 bytes)
Chain issues               Contains anchor

#2
Subject                    DigiCert High Assurance CA-3 
Fingerprint:               a2e32a1a2e9fab6ead6b05f64ea0641339e10011 
Valid until                Sat Apr 02 17:00:00 PDT 2022 (expires in 7 years)
Key                        RSA 2048 bits (e 65537) 
Issuer                     DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA 
Signature algorithm        SHA1withRSA WEAK

#3
Subject                    DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA In trust store Fingerprint: 5fb7ee0633e259dbad0c4c9ae6d38f1a61c7dc25 
Valid until                Sun Nov 09 16:00:00 PST 2031 (expires in 16 years and 7 months)
Key                        RSA 2048 bits (e 65537) 
Issuer                     DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA Self-signed 
Signature algorithm        SHA1withRSA Weak, but no impact on root certificate

Certification Paths
(path# not provided)
#1 Sent by server          (not provided)
.                          Fingerprint: 8391780451d5684847681c413f81d5689a669ddd
.                          RSA 2048 bits (e 65537) / SHA1withRSA WEAK SIGNATURE

#2 Sent by server          DigiCert High Assurance CA-3
.                          Fingerprint: a2e32a1a2e9fab6ead6b05f64ea0641339e10011
.                          RSA 2048 bits (e 65537) / SHA1withRSA WEAK SIGNATURE

#3 Sent by server          DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA Self-signed
.  In trust store          Fingerprint: 5fb7ee0633e259dbad0c4c9ae6d38f1a61c7dc25
.                          RSA 2048 bits (e 65537) / SHA1withRSA
.                          Weak or insecure signature, but no impact on root certificate Configuration

Protocols 
TLS 1.2     No 
TLS 1.1     No 
TLS 1.0     Yes 
SSL 3       No 
SSL 2       No

Cipher Suites (SSL 3+ suites in server-preferred order; deprecated and SSL 2 suites always at the end)
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 (0x4) WEAK     128 
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0x5) WEAK     128 
TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xa)     112 
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x2f)     128 
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x35)     256
```

Comment: Was there no more detail to the error you get? Anyway, Firefox 37 had 2 [changes](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/37.0/releasenotes/) related to SSL/TLS: "Disabled insecure TLS version fallback for site security" and "Improved certificate and TLS communication security by removing support for DSA". One of my HTTPS sites also stopped working after upgrading to 37, but a few days (and some experimenting with settings) later it worked again (I swear every setting was put back as  before).

Answer (score 1):

Though I'm not an expert but I've recently configured a domain to get an A+ rating at SSLLabs, so I've been working on it.

You have two RC4 suites in there, which is [disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/36/Site_Compatibility) as fallback from Firefox 36+. The [default ciphersuites](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.dev.tech.crypto/zlvlj0coFqw) for FF36 are:

```
C02B  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256    N/A: AES+GCM Not in TLS1.0
C02F  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256      N/A: AES+GCM Not in TLS1.0
C00A  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA       * N/A: DSA and ECC
C009  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA       * N/A: DSA and ECC
C013  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA         * N/A:?+FS +ECC
C014  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA         * N/A:?+FS +ECC
0033  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA       * +FS RFC3268:extends TLS1.0
0032  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA            Removed in FF37
0039  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA       * +FS RFC3268:extends TLS1.0
002F  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA                4th choice above (no FS)
0035  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA                5th choice above (no FS)
000A  TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA               3rd choice above (actually 112 bits)
```

(*) These all add Forward Secrecy. I don't think Digicert includes ECC in the chain you're using ([their chains](https://www.digicert.com/digicert-root-certificates.htm)) but it can be requested. A contact is on this [DigiCert ECC information page](https://www.digicert.com/ecc.htm).

Right now, it seems to me you should remove your RC4's, add suites 0033 and 0039, and change the order in which they're presented by your server so they match what Firefox requests. I'm open to correction.

Notes:

- [List of cipher suites and their meanings](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ciphers.html).
- There was temporarily an issue for FF [falling back to RC4 on a second try](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1123932) but probably doesn't affect you.
- SHA1 is deprecated and CBC ciphers are potentially vulnerable to [Lucky13](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucky_Thirteen_attack) side channel timing attack ([paper](http://www.isg.rhul.ac.uk/tls/TLStiming.pdf) by Nadhem AlFardan and Kenny Paterson) and a [bro script](https://github.com/LiamRandall/bro-scripts/blob/master/ssl/lucky-13/detect-lucky-13-threshold.bro) to detect attacks (Liam Randall on github).
- As of 2015-03-19, SSLLabs only tests up to [Firefox 35](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/clients.html).
- Other vendors provide ECC and DSA for free; not linking to vendors because I think that's frowned upon here.